# Mail function in ASP CLASSIC sends literally html tags in the body

Tags: html, email, asp-classic

A few weeks ago I implemented a mail function in my ASP Classic code but it generates a few strange markup / styling errors.

When a mail is send with the Mail function it sometimes outputs html tags literally while the syntax is correct.

**See picture below for the literal html output:**

[image]

As you can see in the picture below the font tag gets displayed literally while it is exactly the same as the other columns, that display correctly. The strange thing about it is that it sometimes displays the font wrong, then some random `<TR>` tag, then 1 border that isn't displayed or a `href` that gets messed up (on click of the href is generates some random %20 characters, while hovering over it it displays the href as it should).

Is this some kind of ASP classic mail function bug or..? It also seems that only one html tag gets displayed literally and never more than 1. Sometimes it also generates no literal tag at all (so it outputs correct).

**The mail function is as follows:**

```vb
Function SendMail(sBody,sEmail)

            set mail=server.createobject("Persits.MailSender")
            Mail.Host = "spamfilter.myWebsite.com" ' Required
            Mail.Port = 587 ' Optional. Port is 25 by default 

            Mail.From = "support@mywebsite.com"

            Mail.FromName = "My Name"

            sEmail = Uploader.Form("EMail")

            Mail.AddAddress sEmail

            Mail.Subject = "Tickets: " & FormSubject
            Mail.Body = sBody
            Mail.IsHTML = True 
            Mail.send

End Function
```

**This is how the mail body is generated:**

```vb
sBody="<font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""black"">Geachte " & FormNaam & ",<br><br>"
                sBody=sBody & "Recentelijk heeft u een ticket aangemaakt betreffende '<b>" & FormSubject &  "</b>'.<br>"
                sBody=sBody & "Wij zullen proberen uw ticket zo snel mogelijk te behandelen. Informatie over uw ticket kunt u hieronder terug vinden." & "<br><br>"

                sBody=sBody &  "<br>"

                sBody=sBody &  "<table>"
                sBody=sBody &  "<tr><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">Verstuur datum</th><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">Voor afdeling</th><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">Soort ticket</th><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">Onderwerp</th><th style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""#000080"">Ticket beschrijving</th></tr>"

                sBody=sBody &  "<tr bgcolor=""#BEC0F7"">"

                sBody=sBody & "<td style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""black"">"
                sBody=sBody &  day(sToday)&"-" & month(sToday) & "-" & year(sToday) 
                sBody=sBody & "</td>"

                sBody=sBody & "<td style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""black"">"
                sBody=sBody & FormAutomatiseringClean
                sBody=sBody & "</td>"

                sBody=sBody & "<td style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""black"">"
                sBody=sBody & FormProbleemClean
                sBody=sBody & "</td>"

                sBody=sBody & "<td style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""black"">"
                sBody=sBody & FormOnderwerp
                sBody=sBody & "</td>"

                sBody=sBody & "<td style=""border: 1px solid black;""><font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""black"">"
                sBody=sBody & FormBeschrijving
                sBody=sBody & "</td></tr>"

                sBody=sBody & "</table><br>"

                    Randomize
                    intLength = 100000
                    intRandom = CInt((Rnd * 10000)Mod intLength) + 1

                'SELECT LAST ID OR ID OF THE SENDER/SUBJECT/SOMETHING UNIQUE
                sBody=sBody & "De status van uw ingediende ticket kunt u bijhouden via de onderstaande knop:<br><br>"
                sBody=sBody & "<table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0""><tr>" 
                sBody=sBody & "<td align=""center"" width=""200"" height=""35"" bgcolor=""#000091"" style=""-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;"">"
                sBody=sBody & "<a href=""http://mywebsite/ticket.asp?type=ticket&ticketid="&TicketID&"&validatie="&FormRecode&""" style=""font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block""><span style=""color: #FFFFFF"">Ticket Status</span></a><br><br>"
                sBody=sBody & "</td></tr> </table><br>"
                sBody=sBody & "Indien de knop het niet doet kunt u de volgende link volgen: http://mywebsite/ticket.asp?type=ticket&ticketid="&TicketID&"&validatie="&FormRecode&"<br><br>"

                sBody=sBody & "With kind regards," & "<br><br>"

                sBody=sBody & "My Company B.V." & "<br><br>"
                sBody=sBody & "<font face=""Calibri, Arial"" style=""font-size:10pt;"" color=""black""><i>My company BV</i>" & "<br>"
                sBody=sBody & "<font face=""Calibri, Arial"" style=""font-size:10pt;"" color=""gray"">GSome adress 22 | Some postal zip | Place" & "<br>"
                sBody=sBody & "<font face=""Calibri, Arial"" style=""font-size:10pt;"" color=""gray"">Some text | Percel number 100" & "<br>"
                sBody=sBody & "<font face=""Calibri, Arial"" style=""font-size:10pt;"" color=""black"">T: " & "<font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=1 color=""gray"">0416-322792" & "<br>"
                sBody=sBody & "<font face=""Calibri, Arial"" style=""font-size:10pt;"" color=""black"">F: " & "<font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=1 color=""gray"">0416-322582" & "<br>"
                sBody=sBody & "<font face=""Calibri, Arial"" style=""font-size:10pt;"" color=""black"">E: support@mysite.com" & "<br>"
                sBody=sBody & "<font face=""Calibri, Arial"" style=""font-size:10pt;"" color=""black"">W: www.mysite.com" & "<br><br>"

                err=SendMail(sBody,sEmail)
```

Comment: It could be some sort of boundary issue with whatever encoding method the Persits mail library uses, try adding some white space e.g. vbCRLF between the sections.   Does any of the data contain any < or >  if so make sure those are escaped as &lt; and &gt;

Comment: It's simple, you don't correctly terminate the tags so `Persits.MailSender` just treats it as text. Not one of the `<font>` tags is correctly terminated with `</font>`. You also haven't structured a valid HTML document *(no `<html>` or `<body>` tags)*.

Comment: All examples on [ASPEmail](http://www.aspemail.com/index.html) show fully qualified HTML structures, so I would start there by making the HTML validate.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Updated the structure with the feedback and it seems (for now) to be working.

Comment: "Is this some kind of ASP classic mail function bug" - If you're not aware, Persits Mailsender is a third party component which you have to buy and install. Look at CDO if you ever need to send emails from another server.

Comment: @John CDO is fine but if you have a licence for [ASPEmail](http://www.aspemail.com) then I'd recommend it as it is far more comprehensive solution then CDO on its own.

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, I really just wanted to make the point that it didn't ship with Windows Server.  Is it any quicker at sending emails through a remote smtp server than CDO?  If it is there's a site where I might try it

Comment: @John Fair point. As for the speed I'm pretty sure it just wraps CDO to be honest, but it gives access to a couple of nice features like queuing messages, digital signatures and some other cool stuff besides. It also integrates well with other Persits components like ASPUpload and ASPEncrypt for example. If you have a licence for it it's definitely worth a bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience using the [`Persits.MailSender`](http://www.aspemail.com/index.html) *(As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073828/mail-function-in-asp-classic-sends-literally-html-tags-in-the-body?noredirect=1#comment46432196_29073828) by [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2087551/john) this is a 3rd party component and not available by default, built-in alternative is CDO)* I've always found that if the HTML is not structured correctly *(i.e. Missing tag terminators)* the results will not always be as expected.

In this specific case it is a HTML snippet not a true document as it is not properly defined;

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is also no termination of `<font>` tags using `</font>` which I suspect is the cause of this problem.

I would however advise that you write HTML that passes validation in the future to avoid such problems.